# How can I use User.Identity.GetUserId() so that model state will be valid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, modelstate

I want to keep track of every transaction happening throughout the application for that I am saving user id of loggedin user using  " User.Identity.GetUserId(); " but I can't assign user id on view elese it'll be public. Trying to save that id from controller

Domain Model

```cs
public class DemoForIdentity
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string  Address { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
// public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Address")] DemoForIdentity demoForIdentity)
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Address")] DemoForIdentity demoForIdentity)
{
    demoForIdentity.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    // Model state will be invalid here. 
    //I can't access User.Identity.GetUserId() from viewmodel and set the value for hidden feild 
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.DemoForidenitity.Add(demoForIdentity);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(demoForIdentity);
}
```

View

```cs
@model Try.Models.DemoForIdentity
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()  
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DemoForIdentity</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        // <div class="form-group">
            // @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Id, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            // <div class="col-md-10">
                // @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Id, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                // @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            // </div>
        // </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Address, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I have commented id from view.

What could be most secured way to save userid everytime?

Comment: Do not use a data model in views. Create a view model. And what makes you think you need to include a hidden field in the view? In the POST method you just get it using `User.Identity.GetUserId()`

Comment: Yup, I'll use view model. When I try to use GetuserId in post method it doesn't execute if loop of modelstate.isvalid . As I alter the model state.

Comment: Your not altering `ModelState`! And you don't even have any validation attributes on your properties so `ModelState` will never be invalid. If it is, then its due to code you have not shown us.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I am confused or messed up. "demoForIdentity.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();" At this point I am altering the model state.

Comment: Your changing the value of a property in your model. You are **not** changing `ModelState`

Comment: Hey man, It's working! Thanks a ton. I can't understand what was problem with me.